# Can wine run any EXE file?

Tags: virtual-machine, wine, playonlinux, winetricks

Sup
Can wine run any EXE file ?

On Windows I have a exe process running then I start a another exe file and it injects in that process. Can I do this using Wine ?

Comment: It's simply not `wine` 's job, it implements some of the Windows API, not specifically designed for injecting into another process. If you want to do this, write the program using   specific process injecting API (linux or wine-supported).

Answer (score 2):

Wine is able to start any exe file, but it implements only a subset of the windows API, and even more important, can out of the box access only a subset of devices and other low-level resources. So this depends on the application. Probably a real hypervisor like KVM is better suited to this use case.